# How can I use views and layouts with Ruby and ERB (not Rails)?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb, rack

How can I use views and layouts with Ruby and ERB (not Rails)?

Today i'm using this code to render my view:

```
def render(template_path, context = self)
 template = File.read(template_path)
 ERB.new(template).result(context.get_binding)
end
```

This works very well, but how can I implement the same function, but to render the template inside a layout? I want to call render_with_layout(template_path, context = self), and so that it will have a default layout.

Comment: `render_with_layout` is a Rails specific thing. Are you prepared to re-implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers!

I solved it finally by doing this, I hope someone else also can find this code useful:

```
def render_with_layout(template_path, context = self)
template = File.read(template_path)
render_layout do
  ERB.new(template).result(context.get_binding)
end
end

def render_layout
layout = File.read('views/layouts/app.html.erb')
ERB.new(layout).result(binding)
end
```

And I call it like this:

```
def index
@books = Book.all
body = render_with_layout('views/books/index.html.erb')
[200, {}, [body]]
end
```

Then it will render my view, with the hardcoded (so far) layout..

Answer (score 5):

Since you tagged it with Sinatra I assume that you us Sinatra.

By default you view is rendered in your default layout called layout.erb

```
get "/" do
   erb :index
end
```

This renders your view index with the default layout.

If you need multiple layouts you can specify them.

```
get "/foo" do
   erb :index, :layout => :nameofyourlayoutfile
end
```

** If you don't use Sinatra you may want to borrow the code from there.*

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [Tilt gem](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) (which I think is what Sinatra uses) you could do something like

```
template_layout = Tilt::ERBTemplate.new(layout)
template_layout.render { 
  Tilt::ERBTemplate.new(template).render(context.get_binding)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Sinatra so it has a good docimentation and one of the topics it's nested layouts (see [Sinatra README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Templates%20with%20%3Ccode%3Eyield%3C/code%3E%20and%20nested%20layouts))

Also good idea to use special default layout file (**layout**.haml or **layout**.erb in your view directory) This file will be always use to render others. This is example for layout.haml:

```
!!!5
%html
  %head
    ##<LOADING CSS AND JS, TILE, DESC., KEYWORDS>
  %body
    =yield ## THE OTHER LAYOUTS WILL BE DISPALYED HERE
    %footer
      # FOOTER CONTENT
```