# Ruby method that yields one ERB template over another

Tags: ruby, erb, yield

I'm need to know how write a method that takes a page ERB below

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

and yield within a layout ERB template below

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edited:**

I am actually looking for a simple method/function which devanand has referred me a link to. Below is what I had worked on, for I have no slightest idea on how to write a method for this.

```
page = "<h1>Hello World</h1>"

layout = "<html>
<head>
  <title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>"

def render_layout(layout)
  ERB.new(layout).result(binding)
end

def render_view_with_layout(view, layout)
  render_layout(layout) do 
    ERB.new(view).result
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got you question.
The following link should answer your question

[How can I use views and layouts with Ruby and ERB (not Rails)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731535/how-can-i-use-views-and-layouts-with-ruby-and-erb-not-rails)

Comment: Thanks   for a moment I got confused with **binding**

But it still got me to where I need to be. Cheers.