# Ruby ERB yield inside another template

Tags: ruby, erb

Note: I'm not using rails, sinatra, or tilt, just ruby's built in ERB.

Suppose I have two erb files:

file1.erb:

```
Start
<%= yield if block_given? -%>
End
```

and file2.erb:

```
<% render('file1.erb') do %>
Some text
<% end %>
```

I'd like to get output that looks like:

```
Start
Some text
End
```

However, with the following ruby code:

```rb
require 'erb'

def render(file)
  content = File.read(file)
  b = binding
  ERB.new(content, trim_mode: '-').result b
end

res = render('file2.erb')
```

I only get "Some Text". And if I change the first line of file2.erb to use `<%=` instead of `<%` then I get a syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from test.rb:9:in `<main>'
    2: from test.rb:6:in `render'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/erb.rb:905:in `result'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/erb.rb:905:in `eval': (erb):1: syntax error, unexpected ')' (SyntaxError)
...t.<<(( render('file1.erb') do ).to_s); _erbout.<< "\\n Some T...
...                              ^
(erb):3: syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting ')'
;  end ; _erbout.<< "\\n".freeze
   ^~~
(erb):4: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
```

Is there some way to get this to work with the 'erb' module?

I can get the yielding to work if I use a block that returns an expression directly, but that won't work for my case.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25789545/2543666) has a solution where the calling code can render a template inside a different layout. But that doesn't really work for me, because I need to define the layout to use inside the template itself (there isn't really an equivalent of a controller in my code).

I thought of maybe doing something like, changing `.result` to `.run`, and running it like:

```
$stdout = outstream
render('file2.erb')
```

But for some reason the results in the output:

```
Start
Some Text
End
Some Text
```

Note the extra "Some Text" at the end.

Comment: I think the syntax error is because ERB doesn't support using a block that starts in a <%=

Answer (score 1):

As you already poined, since we are not outputing the `render` method return value with `<%=` the in first case we are only getting `Some text` in output the rest is just used in processing.

In second when you used `run` with template which is causing the `result` to run twice, first time for `template` which is called in first script file and then second time for `template` which is called inside `file2.erb` `render`.

To solve the problem you can capture the output in a variable and then print the output from the captured variable as below:

**file2.erb**

```rb
<% @result = render('file1.erb') do -%>
<% "Some text\n" -%>
<% end -%>
<%= @result -%>
```

**Output**

```
Start
Some Text
End
```

**Note:**
You can use [`HEREDOC`](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/ruby-heredoc/) to put large amount of text between `<% -%>`

```rb
<% @result = render('file1.erb') do -%>
<%
  <<~EOF
    Some Text
  EOF
-%>
<% end -%>
<%= @result -%>
```

Comment: But then all of content in the body of the block must be inside <% tags. In my real application, it is significantly more complicated than just "Some Text" and itself includes <%= tags.

Comment: @Thayne sorry for delay in reply please check the update answer